# googlesheets can't import expandable table

Tags: html, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, import-table

I can't import the second table of this site on my google sheets: https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/AMZN/financials/annual/balance-sheet

(the table that show when you click on "Liabilities & Shareholders' Equity").

This is my code:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/AMZN/financials/annual/balance-sheet", "table",2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you want is not the 2nd table on the page, it is the 59th table.

Check out the documentation for the `IMPORTHTML` function here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en

The last argument is which table on the page you want. When I inspected the HTML for the page, I found **115** `<table>` elements making up the HTML on the page.

So, your code should look like this:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/AMZN/financials/annual/balance-sheet", "table",59)
```

I just tested this in Google Sheets, and it did import the data.

Comment: This no longer works. Wsj now checks a user agent - if it's not a browser they return a 403 error